# How To Insert PHP Script to Wordpress and HTML sites

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have to figure out how to add some script to both a wordpress and html sites. The client wants to see what it would look like. I have a little experience in HTML and simple wordpress manipulations. Where do I put the code? I tried placing it in different places on my own wordpress site (RoblesDesigns.com) and nothing happened. It's supposed to be a slideshow that displays service providers and each image links to that company's main page. It should look like this: http://www.exitrealtyleadersohio.com/about/profile/1764736/#profile

You can see it if you scroll down and find the stretched out slideshow (I have no idea why it looks like that, I got here after it was created).

**The Code:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="realtor_ads"
src="http://mypreferredserviceproviders.com/realtor/addvertisement/200/175xra4u9yqn86s"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Never link to your website. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Open WP dashboards, then go to appearance, then to editor and open `header.php` and put your script into `<head></head>` tags

Comment: I placed it right before the end tag and my slider (using revolution slider) gave me an error when viewing the site. I placed it right after the <head> tag and nothing shows up.

Comment: I can't see the output, I can't see the code.. Provide more information

Comment: The code they asked me to place? They gave me two different ones. It's this: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

and this: <script type="text/javascript" id="realtor_ads"
src="http://mypreferredserviceproviders.com/realtor/addvertisement/200/175xra4u9yqn86s"></script>

Comment: <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN: basic page needs -->
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title>
        <?php 
            if ($page_title) {
                echo $page_title . ' | '; bloginfo('name');
            } else {
                wp_title('|', true, 'right'); bloginfo('name');
            }
        ?>
    </title>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <?php if ($smof_data['custom_style']) : ?>
    <style>
        <?php echo $smof_data['custom_style']; ?>
    </style>
    <?php endif; ?>

</head>

Comment: There's a bunch of code in between pulling the favicons and logos that will work with iphones, etc in between as well.